# Javascript: Creating a chart representation for absent or present value

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to create a chart in javascript to show when the student/employee is present or absent in the last 10 days.

The chart should look as below. What is the name of the chart and how do I make it? Can you link me to any good source?

[image]

- **Red**:- marks absent days of the particular student
- **Green**:- marks present days of the particular student

I don't even know if it is called a chart and how to make it?

Comment: I would see this as a heatmap. Heatmaps though usually have a scale. The brighter the color the higher the value. Maybe brighter red when more absent days.

Comment: It should be a binary value every day either present or absent. like in excel sheet @dmoo

Comment: Dont think thats a particular problem set the heatmap range between 0 and 1, and only provide 0/1.

Comment: Really what you are describing is a just a table/grid and not a chart, but heatmap is the closest to a chart.